# How do we sort a tables content using update based on some other table value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables both have some values in them,

```
CREATE TABLE one (ID not null, Col1 char, Col2 char, Col3 char, Col4 char, Col5 char);
Insert into one (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5) VALUES (1, 'S', 'D', 'X', 'Y', 'M', 'K');
```

The other table contains what number each alphabet refers to (ex: S= 13, D = 1, X = 7, Y = 3, M = 2, k = 30)

I need to use the two tables with join and update the cols to be ordered from largest to smallest.

Expected result: 1, k, s, x, y, m, d

This is what I tired so far:

```
UPDATE one
INNER JOIN two a on (one.Col1 = a.Colname)
INNER JOIN two b on (one.Col2 = b.Colname) 
INNER JOIN two c on (one.Col3 = c.Colname) 
INNER JOIN two d on (one.Col4 = d.Colname) 
INNER JOIN two e on (one.Col5 = e.Colname) 
SET
one.Col1 = (@temp:=one.Col1), one.Col1 = if ((b.ColValue > (a.ColValue and c.ColValue and d.ColValue and e.ColValue)),one.Col2,@temp), 
one.Col2 = if (one.Col1 = b.Col2, a.CardName, one.Col2);
```

In the above I am also swapping the values based on if the previous value was swapped or not.

I am stuck in trying to swap the rest, I am sure there is an easier way but I really can not think of anything else at the moment. Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean `VALUES (1, 'S', 'D', ...)`? Strings have to have quotes around them.

Comment: Yup, was rushing sorry

Answer (score 0):

Look - does it is what you need?

```
UPDATE one
SET col1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(letter ORDER BY weight DESC) FROM two LIMIT 1), ',', 1), ',', -1),
    col2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(letter ORDER BY weight DESC) FROM two LIMIT 1), ',', 2), ',', -1),
    col3 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(letter ORDER BY weight DESC) FROM two LIMIT 1), ',', 3), ',', -1),
    col4 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(letter ORDER BY weight DESC) FROM two LIMIT 1), ',', 4), ',', -1),
    col5 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(letter ORDER BY weight DESC) FROM two LIMIT 1), ',', 5), ',', -1),
    col6 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(letter ORDER BY weight DESC) FROM two LIMIT 1), ',', 6), ',', -1);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0bc1eef23f18c27f3f07a29d47a9ea40)

Comment: Hi thanx for attempting but no I need to use both tables to update table ones values.

Comment: If so add into the question - table2 (DDL + data, as given for table1), desider result on this (table 1 and tablee 2) data.